# How can I keep track of a div's height in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

#### What I am attempting to do

I would like to keep track of a divs height, so I can dynamically change the distances. The animation needs to travel depending on screen width (when screen is narrow, text stacks and the height changes).

For example, on a full screen the distance is 180, narrow screens are longer.
The calculation below would give me the correct value I believe (80 for 40 margin).

###### In *utils/animation.js*

```js
window.onload = function textDivHeight() {

    divElement = document.querySelector(".textContainer");
    elHeight = divElement.offsetHeight;

    divHeight = elHeight + 80;
    console.log(divHeight)

    return divHeight
}

export const textDiv = textDivHeight();
```

###### In components

```js
import { animationStart, textDiv } from "../../utils/animation";

const Video = () => {
    return (
        <motion.div
            initial = {{ y: -{textDiv} }} // This value I want to be changing on page load.
            animate = {{ y: 0 }}
            transition = {{ delay: animationStart -1.5, duration: 1.2 }}
        >
            <motion.video className = "playVideo"
                autoPlay muted loop

            >
                <source src = "../../src/assets/video.mp4"/>
            </motion.video>
        </motion.div>

    )
}
```

###### The div I'm trying to access (another component)

```js
const IntroText = () => {

    return (
        <div className = "textContainer" id = "textContainer">
```

The problem I am running into is "divElement" not being *defined*, I believe this is due to React and mounting/loading. Is there a way to access and change this value onload?

#### What I've attempted

I've also attempted the use of a useEffect and useState to no avail (example shown below). I have also read through other similar posts and am still getting the error.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
         // code ...

         divsHeight = something

         setDivHeight(divsHeight) // usestate
    }, [])
```

Comment: You can use a MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

You could use `useRef` and grab the height in a similar way to what you're doing with the `querySelector`. I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/competent-pateu-6tpmzp?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A15%2C26) where you can see a demo. You're just going to need to adjust it to your use case. But the idea would be set the ref in the `.textContainer` div using useEffect, and then pass the height to the component that needs it.

```
const divRef = useRef(null);

const [divHeight, setDivHeight] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  if (divRef.current) {
    console.log(divRef.current)
    setDivHeight(divRef.current.offsetHeight - 5)
  }
}, [])

const IntroText = () => {

    return (
        <div ref={divRef} className = "textContainer" id = "textContainer">
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Resize Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resize_Observer_API) addresses this case. You can use it with a [ref](https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs) to create the desired functionality. Here's a contrived example with a [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) — which offers a native resize control on most (desktop) browsers — so that you can test the effectiveness:

> Note: because Stack Overflow content is in English, this demo makes the assumption of a *horizontal* [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode). If that's not the case for some of your users, you'll need to write additional logic for that case. See more details about `blockSize` and `inlineSize` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserverEntry/borderBoxSize).

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEwKYDMCGBXANvTAZzgCVVMBjGAEQHkBZOAXznSghDgCIpyqBaZBwD0FXMFQA7GFwDcAKFCRYieXDgwAnmFSk+MAKK5UIKTAA0ajdt1l0tAEYArVFUvqAyjCjAq9CGjucNiEqAbo6K4WViGodkGxXpgwqJYsbBzcvJQyCvLo2JJUwBCSwaFGJmYAEqjAAOYAFjAAFKjGptJ2AFx69s5RADzVACr0ADKVnTAAfACUvZLYIA6oUKrqFKWE8ADajXVNFnChMLUNzQC6cAC85ahJKS1W6i1ztzNw7VVdGAB0FGwUF40jgAH4vh0zHYAUCQTA-hAIqdzkc4L0AAxBOZ5dSxcKRKgtN4fDbqODAdBwFoAQm+0xhgOBZnevBgQMkCnJcC2kh2kJ+8Du9Oh-yZ8Nx5N5-OwYGQyVQqOat2pL3JZh8qEIvTImCEklwmgAgsDMJpBmRCMAAF6oRyhKAANzWBmkUE0MyC6gWcEdEGAyFJCDV6nQ0Gp0vgGs0cCRXzdEkI72D3O5wmEcCNhEIyy1cEa0BtpRgmFwcAA7j4YMBJPV+CAAqhuiGpdt4AcLkL495NH8HNA0FAAEIQAAeHhtqF2GMuYL7uAgFAA1hPbVzU+pKdStDo4x20TdD9wlis1lx3ijDs0WvvmjiW0w1UxJZs23BeFbbfa1s71ndJKg5Z6J+doOA6v4tLK8opEqMD3tyH6Tt+TprIiYE-qgbRQtI5iIHA-ajr0XD9lAg78ARXDMPB5Jshy1LvDcnyIV+6EoVAfyFBArHOlhgrUUwuG7CKvzoLhl6dpc95WLRUBlLeMAKI++SFMUpSZmAYBvDq+hTGYZKRu+GAqrEdjDGM4wjKgo4wCa5C6dIMwtEsuC4NRBnycZFTYWcV6tLw6DUTJZSDCk1mYNkhl6rQBoxv5NwIP5LCOqW2CoPFAAGAAkCDySwYCjulTAzIMwihSW2QzIp8jyLqVB0PQALZCkJAQBArRCIC0x-PUqCGN5Q6aAAksgLQ8K1MhzDScx-CCg7POogxeD4fiNjMaqDEaGlwMIa0LcIS2+DA-hoJ68j3kAA)

```css
textarea { font-size: 1rem; }
```

```html
<div id="root">Loading&hellip;</div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.23.5/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;

function useElementHeight(elementRef) {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(
    () => elementRef.current ? elementRef.current.offsetHeight : 0,
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!elementRef.current) return;
    const element = elementRef.current;

    const updateHeight = (entries) => {
      for (const entry of entries) {
        // Assumes horizontal writing-mode:
        const height = entry.borderBoxSize[0]?.blockSize;
        if (typeof height === "number") setHeight(height);
      }
    };

    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(updateHeight);
    resizeObserver.observe(element, { box: "border-box" });
    return () => resizeObserver.unobserve(element);
  }, [elementRef, setHeight]);

  return height;
}

function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const height = useElementHeight(ref);
  return <textarea readOnly ref={ref} value={`${height} px`}></textarea>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
);

</script>
```